# Bootstrap Fixed footer with side column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My template have a side column and at the right there are the content. I want fixed footer at the right of side column but not work.

This is the example template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side">
        <?php include("side_menu.php"); ?>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-10">
    <!-- ******** startBody ******** -->
      <?php include("header.php"); ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Text</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-footer"><a href="element.php">...see all</a></div>
                </div>      
        </div>
    </div>

</div>    

    <!-- ******** endBody ******** -->
      <?php include("footer.php"); ?>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using flexbox? This could probably be solved pretty easily with that.

Comment: Demo added please check if this full fills your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Paste all the below content in the URL http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_default&stacked=h to see working demo, hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2" style="background-color:red;">     
       NNNNNNNNN     


    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-10 "style="background-color:green;">  
           BBBBBBBBBBB  <br/>             
    </div>

   <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-lg-10 footer">FFFFFFFFFF<div> 

        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```